# How to check if the react native component is covered by another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Is there a way to check if my component is visible(Not covered by other component) to user?

Example:

```
<Router>
   <Scene component={A} />
   <Scene component={B} />
</Router >
```

I user react-native-router-flux, in SceneA I navigate to SceneB

How can I know SceneA is not the top-most scene in the stack?

Comment: Can you please provide example so that we can understand clearly?

Comment: I have added some more information

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1045 check this if it can solve/help your query.